# Close sap export multiple excel file with vba

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

This is my code for SAP GUI script in which on click of button i am exporting a data to file . i have mutiple rows there would be 100's of file are generated. i have to manually close all file.

can anybody help how to close the all new opened excel file.
What code should i add in it

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If Not IsObject(SAPApp) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = SAPApp.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(wscript) Then
   wscript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   wscript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If

lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lrow
If ws.Cells(i, "G") = True Then

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nfbl3n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/radX_AISEL").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSD_SAKNR-LOW").Text = ws.Range("A" & i)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSD_SAKNR-HIGH").Text = ws.Range("B" & i)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSD_BUKRS-LOW").Text = ws.Range("C" & i)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSD_BUKRS-HIGH").Text = ws.Range("D" & i)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-LOW").Text = ws.Range("E" & i)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-HIGH").Text = ws.Range("F" & i)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-HIGH").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_BUDAT-HIGH").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[3]/menu[1]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = Cells(1, "K").Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Cells(i, "H").Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
End If
Next i
End Sub'''
```

Comment: Your question can be simplified to only one Excel workbook: how to close the window automatically when it opens, and the solution is neither with SAP GUI nor SAP GUI Scripting API, but with classic Windows programming to do an "endless" loop until the Excel window opens, by using `Do: bWindowFound = Wshell.AppActivate("???"): WScript.Sleep 1000: Loop Until bWindowFound`, or possibly  `GetObject(,"Excel.Application")`. There are probably some answers around.

Comment: This is i am using in my excel vba to do task in sap GUI.WScript.Sleep 1000 does not work in VBA for SAP

Comment: The code I posted is incomplete, it was just to help you search the Web for complete codes. It works with VBA, just instantiate WScript object. Of course, a Sleep method is also provided with Excel application.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is evolving. Also the possibilities that were known up to now. Recently you could also try the following.
for example:

```
...
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
'-------------new-------------------------------------------------------
'Is it really a number = 1 or a parameter = i?
myPath = Cells(1, "K").Value
myFileName = Cells(i, "H").Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = myPath
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = myFileName
'not necessary and with a file name shorter than 10 it would even be wrong
'session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

myCount = Workbooks.Count
Do
 DoEvents
 Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
 DoEvents
 If Workbooks.Count > myCount Then Exit Do
Loop

Dim xlApp As Object

Set xlApp = GetObject(myPath & "\" & myFile).Application

For j = 1 To Workbooks.Count
 If LCase(Workbooks(j).Name) = LCase(myFile) Then Exit For
Next j

xlApp.Workbooks(j).Close SaveChanges:=False
Set xlApp = Nothing
'--------------new-------------------------------------------------------

Next i
...
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: thanks scriptman for code but it closes macro file only.

Comment: That's because I didn't have time to test. Now I've taken the time. You can see the result above.

Comment: I tried but it did not worked. first its not setting up path Set xlApp = GetObject(myPath & "\" & myFile).Application. i explcitly tried to set path for first file

Comment: Set xlApp = GetObject("C:\Users\khthakur\Desktop\Khush\test\1.xlsx").Application but then it failed at  xlApp.Workbooks(j).Close SaveChanges:=False
 @scriptman.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my VBA program works fine for me. We can only help you if you present the complete program to us.

Comment: Thats is complete program

Comment: I can only see one of your VBA programs, which is incomplete, and a snippet of code from me. You should show us your current program as a whole. And an example for the first 4 rows of the data that you get from Excel.

Comment: @scriptman- it worked thamks. Also you know how to handle How to Stop the Pop-up; SAP GUI Security.

Answer (score 0):

Any body know how to handle this -How to Stop the Pop-up; SAP GUI Security using VBA script while export the excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8ukD.png)

Comment: The simplest method would be to disable the security settings: (Alt /F12 => Options => Security => Security Options => Status => deactivated) If you need special settings, you would have to ask someone from IT in your company.

Comment: Is there vba script for it? if it get disabled using vba script

Comment: No, it does not exist. It only has to be set manually once. Or you can run a REG file:Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SAP\SAPGUI Front\SAP Frontend Server\Security]
"SecurityLevel"=dword:00000000

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for solution to close excel files that are opened automatically by SAP after exporting. here is my solution.
SAP exports excel in other Excel instances ( sometimes it creates 2 or 3 other instances). So just calling Workbooks("name.xlsx").close wont work.

here is my program to close all excel files opened by SAP.
Suppose my macro program is written in "Acetate.xlsm", and SAP generated 3 excel files named a.xlsx, b.xlsx, c.xlsx

```
Sub Close_excel()
    Dim xlApp as Object
    Dim filepath as String
    Dim wb_name as String
    Dim i as Long
'define absolute path to excel files opened by SAP
file_path = Array("....\a.xlsx", "....\b.xlsx", ".....\c.xlsx")
wb_name = Array("a.xlsx", "b.xlsx", "c.xlsx")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

For i = LBound(file_path) to UBound(file_path) do
    Set xlApp = GetObject(filepath(i)).Application
    
   'Avoid closing "Acetate.xlsm" which contains this macro
    If xlApp.Workbooks(wb_name(i)).Name <> "Acetate" then 
       xlApp.Workbooks(wb_name(i)).Close True
       Set xlApp = Nothing
    End If
    Next i
  End Sub
```